# Component with multiple checkboxes and ONE v-model

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I'm building "base" components for my application, mostly for form management. So far I've made a custom  **input**, **textarea**, **select**, and **radio**. However, all those components only have "one" value at a time.

For radios and checkboxes, my component builds multiple radios/checkboxes at once, all attached to the same v-model. Howevever, my checkbox component is not working as intended. **Instead of storing "all the checked checkboxes" in an array in the v-model, it only registers the last one clicked :(**.

How can I override the "change" event so that it updates the attached model accordingly, by adding/removing the element from the array?

Here's my code for the checkbox component:

```js
/**
 * @description Component used to display a group of checkboxes
 * @author Jordan Kowal
 * @date 2019-11-30
 * @param name String, name attribute
 * @param alignment String, defines item alignment and should be "centered", "left", or "right"
 * @param block Boolean, whether items are displayed as "block" or "inline-block"
 * @param entries Array, list of objects with the following keys: label, value, active
 * @param errors Array, list of error messages
*/
Vue.component("checkbox-group", {
    props: {
        name: String,
        alignment: String,
        block: Boolean,
        entries: Array,
        errors: Array,
    },
    template:
        "<div class='field'>\
            <p class='help is-danger' v-for='message in errors'>\
                @{message}\
            </p>\
            <div class='control' :class='\"has-text-\" + alignment'>\
                <template v-for='entry in entries'>\
                    <label class='checkbox'>\
                        <input\
                            type='checkbox'\
                            :name='name'\
                            :checked='entry.active'\
                            :value='entry.value'\
                            @change='$emit(\"input\", $event.target.value)'\
                        />\
                        @{entry.label}\
                    </label>\
                    <br v-if='block'>\
                </template>\
            </div>\
        </div>",
});
```

Exemple of use:

```html
<checkbox-group
    name="id"
    alignment="centered"
    :block="true"
    v-model="languageForm.fields.languages"
    :entries="languageForm.entries.languages"
    :errors="languageForm.errors.languages"
></checkbox-group>
```

## EDIT:

Solution provided by **Michal Levý** is working perfectly

Comment: Is the `name` you're binding to the input element a different value for each checkbox? It should be `entry.name`, no?

Comment: If checkboxes/radios have the same "name" attribute, that means they relate to the same form field. The consequence is that, when submiting the form, an array of the checked value will be submitted for said field. So here it will be id=[1, 2, etc.] if you submit the form

Comment: Could the issue be that you're replacing the value of the entire array each time a box is ticked instead of pushing the value to the existing array? Ie., instead of `@change='$emit(\"input\", $event.target.value)'`, there should be a different event handler specifically for pushing/removing items from the array.

Comment: Yes, this is my current problem. `@change='$emit(\"input\", $event.target.value)'` is the Vuejs guideline, but it works for "single-value input". So radio, select, input, and "single checkboxes". But it doesn't work for "several related checkboxes". This is exactly my problem. I COULD override the event, but I don't know how to target my v-model with a method from WITHIN my component

Comment: Does this help? https://www.dyn-web.com/tutorials/forms/checkbox/same-name-group.php

Comment: Not really but thanks. My problem is: how do I target my "v-model" prop from within my component's method. I've edited by post to show a working "but not so clean" solution, which illustrate my issue

Comment: This is what I've done in the added example. However, it forces me to add a "model" prop which is redundant with the "v-model" used in HTML.

Comment: Props are [one-way, downward data flow](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#One-Way-Data-Flow). You can't v-model a prop. You have to send the data back with an event to the parent.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Michal provided a solution (see below) that follows the same logic you pointed out

Comment: is that [bulma](https://bulma.io/)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Take a look what `v-model` on custom components [does](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Using-v-model-on-Components)

```
<mycomponent v-model="data" />
```

is same as

```
<mycomponent 
  v-bind:value="data"
  v-on:input="data= $event" />
```

So if you do `$emit("input", $event.target.value)` inside of your component, whatever `$event.target.value` is, it replaces your model. But you need an "input" event so the `v-model` on your component works. `value` emitted just has to be in the same format as a model you are receiving.

On top of that whats the point of having a model and at the same time support `entries.active` ? It's clear duplicity. Passed model should be only thing that decides whether checkbox is checked or not....

Do it like this:

```js
Vue.component("checkbox-group", {
  props: {
    name: String,
    alignment: String,
    block: Boolean,
    entries: Array,
    errors: Array,
    value: Array
  },
  computed: {
    model: {
      get() { return this.value },
      set(newValue) { this.$emit('input', newValue)}
    }
  },
  template: `
  <div class="field">
    <p class="help is-danger" v-for="message in errors" :key="message">
      {message}
    </p>
    <div class="control" :class="'has-text-' + alignment">
      <template v-for="entry in entries">
        <label class="checkbox" :key="entry.value">
          <input
            type="checkbox"
            :name="name"
            :value="entry.value"
            v-model="model"
          />
          {{ entry.label }}
        </label>
        <br v-if="block" :key="'br_'+entry.value"/>
      </template>
    </div>
  </div>
`
});
```

Changes:

1. added `value` prop - its set by Vue to a value inside `v-model` attribute of your component
2. instead of binding `:checked` and `@change` on each `input`, we use `v-model` instead as it handles all the array slicing/pushing (model is an array)
3. But because our model (`value` prop) is from prop, we cannot us it directly in `v-model` (child cannot update prop from parent). In this kind of situations the [computed with setter](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Setter) are very useful.

   1. when the computed is read, we return value of `value` prop
   2. when the computed is set (by `v-model` used on `input`), we just `$emit` the value to the parent
   3. Parent will update its property used in `v-model` and our child component receives the new value via a `value` prop

[Working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/component-with-multiple-checkboxes-and-one-v-model-879hy)

### Update

As this my old answer still receives upvotes I have decided to update it. Previous version was working but had one little quirk - component was not reactive to potential `value` prop changes from the parent . This new version is simply better - works in all cases and is less code...

### Bonus - Vue 3 version

```js
Vue.component("checkbox-group", {
  props: {
    name: String,
    alignment: String,
    block: Boolean,
    entries: Array,
    errors: Array,
    modelValue: Array
  },
  emits: ['update:modelValue'],
  computed: {
    model: {
      get() { return this.modelValue },
      set(newValue) { this.$emit('update:modelValue', newValue)}
    }
  },
  template: `
  <div class="field">
    <p class="help is-danger" v-for="message in errors" :key="message">
      {message}
    </p>
    <div class="control" :class="'has-text-' + alignment">
      <template v-for="entry in entries" :key="entry.value">
        <label class="checkbox">
          <input
            type="checkbox"
            :name="name"
            :value="entry.value"
            v-model="model"
          />
          {{ entry.label }}
        </label>
        <br v-if="block" />
      </template>
    </div>
  </div>
`
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explaination and the working example. I've implemented your solution and it works like a charm! I do have a follow-up question though: I tried applying the same logic to my radio-group component (EXACTLY the same but radio) and the 'check based on v-model' is not working. For the checkboxes, I got the language list from an API, push the values of the active one in my model, and render the component --> checkboxes are then checked based on model. For my radio, I do "mymodel = activeone" (rather than .push()) but on rendering, no radio is checked :(

Comment: OK I found the nature of this issue: the watcher is not triggered when I do `languageForm.fields.languages = 1` (which is the value I get from the initial API call). As opposed to checkboxes where I would be using .push() for every active checkboxes from the API, and it would trigger the watcher every time. I've tried using `$set` and `$forceUpdate()` but the watcher is never triggered by this action (it works when clicking on radio afterwards, but not the initial setup)

Comment: I fixed it by using the official Vuejs method: `@change='$emit(\"input\", $event.target.value)'` alongside `:checked='value == entry.value'` (without using the data/watch combo we used for the checkboxes)

Answer (score 0):

Repeat the checkboxes as necessary, using v-model with the same name, different values.

Such as this HTML:

```
<form>
  <input type="checkbox" id="support_1" value="1" v-model="support">
  <label for="support_1">Restart the app</label>

  <input type="checkbox" id="support_2" value="2" v-model="support">
  <label for="support_2">Log off and on</label>
</form>
<p>
{{ support }}
</p>
```

And the code:

```
data() {
  return {
    support: [],
  }
},
```